# Why does the right verb ] returns value but not the left verb [?

Tags: j

J newbie here.

The verb *right* `]` gives a mean to return the result of an assignment. I guess that `x =: 1` is evaluated and has the value 1 and then it is passed to `]` which returns the value of the right argument (or maybe that's `]` which forces the assignment to have a value).

```
   ] x =: 1
1
   x
1
```

But it doesn't work with *left* `[`. Why is that ? I thought that putting `x =: 1` on the left of `[` would have been enough. What's the difference between both of them ?

```
   x =: 1 [
|syntax error
|   x=:    1[
```

Moreover, when we evaluate the expression below, there is no feedback on the console, the assignments have been silently made. Why is that ?

```
   x =: i.10 [ n =: 2
   x
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   n
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applied monadically (i.e. with only a right argument), both `[` and `]` are the verb [**Same**](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help807/dictionary/d500.htm), which just returns its argument unchanged.
The reason why `x =: 1 [` is a syntax error is that you're trying to evaluate `[` dyadically (i.e. with two arguments) with only a left argument.

The output in the last example has to do with the order of evaluation ― in J, this happens right to left.
This means that `x =: i.10 [ n =: 2` is the same as `x =: (i. (10 [ (n =: 2)))`, and it's evaluated as follows:

1. `n =: 2`, i.e. `n` is assigned value 2, then the result is used in the next verb
2. `10 [ n`, i.e. 10 *left* `n`, which is just 10
3. `i.10`, i.e `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
4. `x =: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

There is nothing printed to the console, because the last action is an assignment. 
Here, you can use `[` or `]` (monadically) to have the final result printed in addition to being assigned, i.e.

```
    ] x=: i.10 [ n =: 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: I started reading "J For C Programmers" and it was the right thing to do. I wouldn't have asked that question if I did it sooner. I also think the verb `;:` is very useful when learning the language. Found it in "An Implementation of J".